# Vue.js disable component during ajax request

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuex

I'm looking for a simple solution for the following problem:

I have a Vue component button with which I can make an ajax request. I would like to disable this button while the request is pending (to prevent multiple requests).

Comment: _"I don't want to maintain the request state inside the button component"_ <- not entirely sure what this means. I'd use `:disabled="someBooleanDataValue"` and set `this.someBooleanDataValue` appropriately

Comment: How is the AJAX request made? Directly in the component or via a Vuex _action_?

Comment: I send the request via a vuex action

Comment: So the button dispatches the action?

Comment: yes, the button dispatches the action

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Sounds like you want your action to set (commit) a flag when it starts and then clear it when it ends.

Try something like this in Vuex...

```js
state: {
  loading: false
},
mutations: {
  isLoading (state) {
    state.loading = true
  },
  doneLoading (state) {
    state.loading = false
  }
},
actions: {
  doAjaxRequest ({ commit }) {
    commit('isLoading')
    return doSomeAjaxRequest().then(res => {
      // success
    }).catch(err => {
      // oh noes
    }).finally(() => {
      commit('doneLoading')
    })
  }
}
```

Now in your component, you can map the `loading` state and use it to disable your button, eg

```html
<template>
  <button :disabled="loading" @click="doAjaxRequest">Do AJAX!</button>
</template>
<script>
  import { mapState, mapActions } from 'vuex'
  export default {
    computed: mapState(['loading']),
    methods: mapActions(['doAjaxRequest'])
  }
</script>
```

---

Alternatively, you can maintain the progress of the request within your component if your action returns a promise (as above). For example, say your button has

```html
<button :disabled="loading" @click="doTheThing">Do the thing!</button>
```

and

```js
data () {
  return { loading: false }
},
methods: {
  doTheThing() {
    this.loading = true
    this.$store.dispatch('someAjaxActionThatReturnsAPromise').finally(() => {
      this.loading = false
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: Alternative way has been worked for me. Thanks. How to show success message after async request complete?

Answer (score 0):

State.js:

```
state: {
  pendingRequest: false
},
actions: {
  fetchRequest: async function(context) {
    context.state.pendingRequest = true
    let req = await fetch(url)
    let data = await req.json()
    context.state.pendingRequest = false
  }
}
```

Component.vue:

```
<button :disabled='$store.state.pendingRequest' @click="$store.dispatch('fetchRequest')">Button</button>
```

Comment: state mutations should always be done via a `commit`. I'm not even sure Vuex will let you directly manipulate `state` on the `context`

Comment: It will let directly manipulate `state` on the `context`, but I agree with you, it's not the best practice.

Comment: You can skip the action but not the mutation.

Comment: Are you sure about that? Says [here](https://vuex.vuejs.org/api/#state-2) it's **read-only**. If it actually works, I doubt it's _reactive_

Comment: Looks like an actual bug. Even in [strict mode](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/strict.html), it's not throwing any errors ~ https://jsfiddle.net/r1z0a4gp/7/

Comment: Because your fiddle used the minified version of `vuex.js`, all errors were suppressed. Here it is, throwing errors ~ https://jsfiddle.net/r1z0a4gp/8/

Answer (score -1):

I found another solution: It automatically generates a vuex module for the registered endpoints, watch those endpoints via axios interceptors and sets the proper 'pending' state values based on the status of the related requests.

https://github.com/pharkasbence/pending-request-tracker